# Defining Equivalence Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X denote the set of polynomials with real coefficients. The relation: $p\sim q$ if:

$\{x: p(x)=0\} = \{y: q(y)=0\}$.

(a.) Is this an equivalence relation? Check all properties and give examples if properties do not hold.

Just by logically thinking it through, I believe this is an equivalence relation. I'm having trouble proving it though. Is it enough to say that it is reflexive because $\{x: p(x)=0\} = \{y: p(y)=0\}$ ?
And for symmetric, is it enough to say that because $\{x: p(x)=0\} = \{y: q(y)=0\}$, then $\{y: q(y)=0\} = \{x: p(x)=0\}$ ?

Do I need to do more specific element chasing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this relation, two polynomials are precisely related if they have the same roots. I wouldn't get too mixed up with the set notation. It should be clear that any polynomial has the same roots as itself, that when p has the same roots as q then q has the same roots as p, and that if p and q have the same roots, and q and r have the same roots, then so do p and r.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function $f:X\rightarrow\wp(\mathbb R)$ that sends each polynomial to its set of roots. Then $$p\sim q\iff f(p)=f(q)$$

This makes it easy to show that it is an equivalence relation:

- $f(p)=f(p)$
- $f(p)=f(q)\Rightarrow f(q)=f(p)$
- $f(p)=f(q)\wedge f(q)=f(r)\Rightarrow f(p)=f(r)$